# How is my TicTacToe game returning the winner as X when it was O

Tags: javascript

I am a relatively new programmer and I have created a Tic Tac Toe game with a way to alert the user who won the game. The problem is, when O wins diagonally, It retaines an alert when X won the game. I can't seem to find a problem in the code.

My source code is at this URL: https://justpaste.it/6t0zo

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
<style>
  body {
  "Arial", Times, serif;
}
.row div{
padding: 10px;
border: 1.25px solid black;
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
float:left;
}
.row{
clear:both;
</style>
</head>
<body>
Click to play Tic Tac Toe<br/>
<p>               </p>
<button onclick="location.reload();">Play Again</button>
<p>               </p>
<div>
<div class="row">
<div id="0_0" onclick="place(this)"></div>
<div id="1_0" onclick="place(this)"></div>
<div id = "2_0" onclick="place(this)"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div id="0_1" onclick="place(this)"></div>
<div id="1_1" onclick="place(this)"></div>
<div id = "2_1" onclick="place(this)"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div id="0_2" onclick="place(this)"></div>
<div id="1_2" onclick="place(this)"></div>
<div id = "2_2" onclick="place(this)"></div>
</div>
</div>


<script>
var currentPlayer = "O";
var won = false;
function place(box) {
if (box.innerText !="" || won) return;
box.innerText = currentPlayer;
currentPlayer == "O" ? currentPlayer = "X" : currentPlayer = "O"
checkGameBoard(currentPlayer);
}
function checkGameBoard(currentPlayer) {
for (var i=0; i <= 2; i++) {
checkWinner(document.getElementById(i + "_0").innerText,
document.getElementById(i + "_1").innerText,
document.getElementById(i + "_2").innerText, currentPlayer);
checkWinner(document.getElementById("0_" + i).innerText,
document.getElementById("1_" + i).innerText,
document.getElementById("2_" + i).innerText, currentPlayer);
}
checkWinner(document.getElementById("0_0").innerText,
document.getElementById("1_1").innerText,
document.getElementById("2_2").innerText);
checkWinner(document.getElementById("0_2").innerText,
document.getElementById("1_1").innerText,
document.getElementById("2_0").innerText);

}
function checkWinner(first,second,third, currentPlayer) {
if(first != "" && first == second && first == third) {
  if (currentPlayer == "X"){
    alert(" Winner is O!" );
  }
  else {
    alert(" Winner is X!" );
  }
won = true
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please may you include the code in the question? Consider using a stack snippet.

Comment: You don't pass `currentPlayer` to the last 2 checks.

Comment: `if (currentPlayer == "X") alert(" Winner is O!" )`...

Answer (score 0):

Usually StackOverflow isn't a children playground, but you two boys (you and @hacker19374) are so funny, so I decided to explain you what happened.

In fact, your question already answered by @TiiJ7, who said: "You don't pass `currentPlayer` to the last 2 checks". If you don't understand what does it mean, let me explain you.

Your `checkWinner(first, second, third, currentPlayer)` function awaits four parameters. Wheh you called this function inside the `for` loop, you give it all the four of them:

```
for (var i=0; i <= 2; i++) {
checkWinner(document.getElementById(i + "_0").innerText,
document.getElementById(i + "_1").innerText,
document.getElementById(i + "_2").innerText, currentPlayer);
checkWinner(document.getElementById("0_" + i).innerText,
document.getElementById("1_" + i).innerText,
document.getElementById("2_" + i).innerText, currentPlayer);
}
```

But when you call it last two times to check diagonals, you didn't pass the fourth `currentPlayer` parameter to that function passing only three of them:

```
checkWinner(document.getElementById("0_0").innerText,
document.getElementById("1_1").innerText,
document.getElementById("2_2").innerText);
checkWinner(document.getElementById("0_2").innerText,
document.getElementById("1_1").innerText,
document.getElementById("2_0").innerText);
```

When you called your `checkWinner` function this way, the fourth parameter gets an [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) value inside that function code. So when you do this check

```
  if (currentPlayer == "X"){
    alert(" Winner is O!" );
  }
  else {
    alert(" Winner is X!" );
  }
```

and the value of `currentPlayer` variable is `undefined`, it would alert you that the winner is X since the check is not passed. Value of `currentPlayer` isn't `X`, but it isn't `O` as well, it is undefined.

Now look how much simple the life would be if instead the

```
function place(box) {
if (box.innerText !="" || won) return;
box.innerText = currentPlayer;
currentPlayer == "O" ? currentPlayer = "X" : currentPlayer = "O"
checkGameBoard(currentPlayer);
}
```

you'd use

```
function place(box) {
if (box.innerText !="" || won) return;
box.innerText = currentPlayer;
checkGameBoard(currentPlayer);
currentPlayer == "O" ? currentPlayer = "X" : currentPlayer = "O"
}
```

i.e. switch the player after checking winning condition, not before. That way instead of

```
  if (currentPlayer == "X"){
    alert(" Winner is O!" );
  }
  else {
    alert(" Winner is X!" );
  }
```

you could use just

```
alert(" Winner is " + currentPlayer + "!" );
```

which would make your debugging much easier when you got something like "Winner is undefined!"

Moreover, you can skip passing `currentPlayer` as the parameter to your functions at all. You already have a global variable `currentPlayer` and it is available inside all of your functions. In fact you already use that variable inside the `place` function. Read the ["Scope Is Visibility, THIS is Context"](https://medium.com/0xcode/scope-is-visibility-this-is-context-29bda2ca45b4) article, it should explain you some JavaScript concepts.

Now if you understand all the above and want to practice in programming some more, I can propose an advanced task for you. Your playboard should have a label showing who is the current player - "Current player is ...". Label should change after each move, and if soneone win, label should show "The winner is ...".